# Odd behavior in jquery `.on('click')`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a slider that displays media files (img,video and pdf), and those media files can be selected to do some operations with them (deleting & attaching), so anyways, initially I made a class called `selected-media` which had a shadow, this worked ok, but it was pretty ugly (you know, media files can change in aspect ratio and whatnot, and this shadow was applied on the div containing the actual `<img>, <video>`, not the media itself). So I decided to google some ways to make this shadow dynamic, so that it was applied not on the div but around the img itself.

To do that I followed the SO answer and did this:

```
.selected-media{
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 25px darkturquoise);
    filter: url(an_url);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";

}
```

Now funnily, even though the url is always the same, this shadow IS dynamic somehow, and it does exactly what I wanted it to. This is good because I'm using flask for the backend and dynamically feeding an url into css is a big pain in the butt.

However there was a problem, a weird one as well, and that presented itself when I added the pdf support.

Here is the structure of the slider:

```
<div id="media-slider">
    <div class="selectable selected-media" id="single-media-5">
        <img class="single-media" src="img-url">
    </div>
    <div class="selectable selected-media" id="single-media-26">
        <div style="height: 100px; text-align:center">
            <img class="single-media" src="\\static\\resources\\pdf-placeholder-icon.png" >
            <p>'+ pdf_name +'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the weird behavior i am talking about:

This is the expected result

[image: desc]

However if I click on the text this consistently happens (not sure if you can see it, but the shadow is applied to the text as well)

[image]

And this is the code that handles those events:

```
$(document).on("click","#media-slider > div.selectable", function (event) {

        if (!event.currentTarget.classList.contains("selected-media")){
            event.currentTarget.classList.add("selected-media");

        }

        else {
            event.currentTarget.classList.remove("selected-media");

        }

});
```

Now, the funny thing is that jQuery is not adding any class to the `<p>` element, the html looks identical in the two cases shown above. I'm not sure what is happening here, of course if you click on the text it should still apply the effect on the img, but just there.

Comment: Do you want to do css change on only image?

Comment: Yes, thats right